# Is there a chat for meta in beta?

Tags: discussion

estos bona por babili ĉi tie pri hazardaj aferoj, eble.
I wonder if stack exchange is biased against esperanto "Please use proper grammar", I doubt it has an esperanto grammar parser

Comment: FWIW, there is a discussion group on Telegram about the StackExchange site here: https://telegram.me/joinchat/EAZleUFPe6Dd_50FE6Co-A

Answer (score 2):

There's a chat link in the footer of the site:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=esperanto.stackexchange.com

And on the topic of grammar, it's only as regulated by the users themselves.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any chat associated with the meta site. As with the other sites, the chat is associated only to the main site. That is evident looking at the Stack Exchange menu, on the top: There is a *chat* link only for the main site.

> [image: screenshot]

We can create a chat room to discuss any of the aspects that would be subject of questions on the meta site, if there is the need.